# Regular expression with the same opening and closing optional tag

Tags: regex

I need a help with this regexp..

using

```
/\{block:(Posts|Photos|Videos)(\s\[.*?\])?\}(\s?[^\"]+\s?)\{\/block\}/U
```

i get `{block:Posts}abcdef{/block}` from this:

```
<div>
 {block:Posts [a=1, b=2]}
  abcdef
 {/block}
</div>
```

But if my text is like this:

```
<div>
 {block:Posts [a=1, b=2]}
  {block:Text}
   abcdef
  {/block}
 {/block}
</div>
```

i get `{block:Posts}{block:Text}abcdef{/block}` because it's based on the first `{/block}` found in text.

A simple way to avoid this is using `{/block:Posts}` to close the block, but how can I do that since the opening block tag is optional (Posts|Photos|Videos)? If I open the block with Photos I must be sure it has to be closed with `{/block:Photos}`.

Using `/\{block:(Posts|Photos|Videos)(\s\[.*?\])?\}(\s?[^\"]+\s?)\{\/block\:(Posts|Photos|Videos)\}/U` of course doesn't help...

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!!

PS
Is it possible, modifying the regex above, to get the optional parameters `a` and `b` as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an overall better solution for your problem, but you can use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in this case, as `(Posts|Photos|Videos)` is capture group already:

```
\{\/block:\1\}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the optional parameters `[a=1, b=2]` as an array? array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2)

Comment: So your language is PHP I assume? I think you have to extract that text and process it later on.

Comment: Yes it is. So you recommend to process it later? Assuming I get the params in plain text like this `[a=1, b=2]`, would you use an explode (or stuff like that) or another regex?

Comment: ah.. you wrote "There might be an overall better solution".. can you suggest that?

Comment: No, otherwise I would have ;) I was just thinking about whether your expression could be simplified or whether there is a library which lets you define your own template language (and parse it).

Comment: I've just realized that if my code is `{block:Posts}PLAINTEXT{/block:Posts}` the regex works fine, but if there's HTML inside the block `{block:Posts}<div id="xyz">some text inside HTML tag</div>{/block:Posts}` the regex doesn't work anymore...! How can I fix that?

Comment: You should probably changes this part `(\s?[^\"]+\s?)` into `(.*?)` or `([^{]*)`. The `"` in your original expression will prevent it from matching (HTML attributes).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
\{block:(Posts|Photos|Videos)(\s\[.*?\])?\}(\s?[^\"]+\s?)\{\/block\1\}
```

Note the added backreference `\1` at the end. The backreference will match whatever was matched by the first group, i.e. the first pair of parenthesis, in our case `(Posts|Photos|Videos)`.

Note however that in general regular expressions are too limited to parse languages like HTML as explained by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Languages which require counting of opening entities (like brackets or tags) and then matching the exact number of closing entities can't be expressed using regular expressions. Another example of a language that isn't regular for this reason is the language of arithmetic expressions with parenthesis or a language composed of strings of the form *aa...abb...b* with the same number of *a* and *b*. General proof of this fact uses the [Pumping Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Note also that regular expressions as used in software tools are usually a bit more powerful than bare mathematical regular expressions due to a number of additions beyond basic operations of union, concatenation and Kleene star that are provided by these software tools. Backreferences themselves constitue a major enhancement of regular expressions and allow one to express languages that are not considered regular in the [mathematical sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). This is why your problem has a solution at all. Counting of opening and closing entities is still impossible, though.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a Tumblr like theme parser that can allow me to use {block} to let users render certain contents (such as news, photos, videos, ...) in the way they like.. Reading the post and the link you suggested really taught me a lot and of course I know that writing a fast and reliable code parser is not easy at all.. At the moment regex is the best I can deal with.. But I'll work to improve that! Can you suggest me some documentation useful to do that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to parse a simple language with opening and closing entities (here: {block:...} and {/block}) you may find that a simple *recursive decent parser* is a good solution. These are more powerful than regular expressions, but still very easy to program (example code is in this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). If your needs go beyond that you may want to use a compiler-compiler like yacc or bison to generate a parser for you, but most of them will require you to come up with a formal grammar for the language you need to parse.

Comment: Also, you can implement a recursive decent parser in any language of your choice, while compiler-compilers impose some limitations. Before you decide, you should however ensure that RDP is powerful enough to parse what you need.

Comment: I've just realized that if my code is `{block:Posts}PLAINTEXT{/block:Posts}` the regex works fine, but if there's HTML inside the block `{block:Posts}<div id="xyz">some text inside HTML tag</div>{/block:Posts}` the regex doesn't work anymore...! How can I fix that?

Comment: Your regexp disallows double-quotes (") between {block...} and {/block...}: (\s?[^\"]+\s?).